# Creating a CanBuildFrom in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm starting to learn Scala and have an issue with `.map`. I think I need to define a CanBuildFrom by hand, but I have no idea how to do it. I have had a look at some introductions, but while I understand the purpose, I cannot figure out an implementation.

So to shorten my code, I have defined a type alias.

`type Dice = Vector[(Int,Int)]`

I have created an implicit class to add methods to that Vector.

```
   implicit class DiceMethods(dice: Dice){  
     private def d(x : Int) = // some method

     def roll : Dice = dice map( case (x: Int, y: Int) => (0, d(x) + y) )
   }
```

The compiler screams at me, when I use `map`.So i guess, I need an `implicit object someFunkyName extends CanBuildFrom` but the rest is beyond me. Or maybe there is some other problem.

Comment: Use curly braces `{}` when defining a partial function (i.e. surrounding the `case` statement).

Comment: OK. That seems to work. _That_ would never have occured to me. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, the compiler error isn't very informative in cases like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not worry about `CanBuildFrom`

use `map { case .... }` instead of `map ( case ...)`

```
implicit class DiceMethods(dice: Dice){  
     private def d(x : Int) = // some method

     def roll : Dice = dice map { case (x: Int, y: Int) => (0, d(x) + y)  }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you. The compiler error was "Cannot resolve reference 'map' with such signature". That lead me down the wrong track.

Comment: I only see `illegal start of simple expression`. Was that in IntelliJ? I'd also recommend not skipping dots until you know basic syntax: `dice.map(f)`.